# putExtra String Intent Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    m = lv.getAdapter().getItem(info.position).toString();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You clicked !"+m, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this Fixture?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //listAdapter.remove(m);

            Intent i  = new Intent(Afc.this.getApplicationContext(), WebViewExample.class);
            i.putExtra("Key", m); 
            startActivity(i);   
        }
```

//new class activity WebView/////////////

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
      String addOn = extras.getStringExtra("key",m);
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You clicked !"+addOn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hi I am passing a string with an intent, its giving me a error in the new activity on the variable m, inside the getStringExtra("key",m);.  can anyone help?

Am I doing this the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key of putExtra is case sensitive. One time you use

> key

and in the another

> Key

You should use key or Key in both cases.

In any case use getStringExtra("key") instead of getStringExtra("key", m). As you can see in the d[ocumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) there isn't a getStringExtra method that takes two parameters. To explain: your variable m can't be resolved because you just declared it in your first class but not in the second.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo from pasting it in, the error says "m cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Thanks Harinder that is the real problem. I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys I cant rate yet but thanks, what I was doing is putting `i.putExtra("Key", m);` and `String addOn = extras.getStringExtra("Key",m);` and should of had `i.putExtra("Key", m);` and `String addOn = extras.getStringExtra("Key");` and the line `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); ` should have been `Intent extras = getIntent();`  .  I am new to this website wil I update my answer or just leave it?

Comment: You can leave your question as it is and if you want you can upvoted the answers and accept one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and getStringExtra("key",m);??? is Wrong USE getStringExtra("key") ;